# Trying to check all the supported cipher suites of a website, having trouble with chacha20 and poly1035 in java

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, cryptography

Like I have mentioned that I have trouble checking for Cipher Suites like

- OLD_TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
- TLS_CECPQ1_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256

These are all latest cipher suites which are said to be faster.
I searched everywhere and I found only one solution i.e **JCE Unlimited Strength**
Which I got made the changes in JRE it didn't work though it gave few more cipher suites result i.e **AES256** were now displayed.

One thing I have understood is JAVA doesn't have not added support for above Cipher Suites.
So I need to add these suites on my own (But I haven't came across any solution for it). A basic start will also be really helpful

Thanks to [jww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww). Because of Jeff I have reached here till now :)

**Thank's all. I performed partial handshake in order to achieve it since java by default doesn't support all the cipher suites provided by us. So performing pratial handshake did the work for me.**

Comment: Are you talking about pure Java or about some application server?

Comment: Core Java i.e Pure Java....
I also came across something called as bouncycastle can this be of any help
How to use it?

Comment: If Java doesn't support those suites, they aren't present, so you can't check for them with Java. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I know java doesn't support all the cipher suites since they are not present in the supported Cipher Suite list. So my question is how can I check for all the cipher suites that I provide for a particular SSL website.
I figured out partial handshake could be a way out. I don't know how to perform it.